# prefix a class name with jquery

Tags: jquery, class, prefix

my question seems simple but I don't find a solution. I have some code on my web page like this :

```
<code class="bash">
...
<code class="markdown">
```

And I would like to use Prism library to have a syntax highlighting. But it requires to have a class like this

```
<code class="language-bash">
...
<code class="language-markdown">
```

So my question is, how in JQuery do I add the "language-" before the language naming ?

I have searched a lot, but prepend does not work with class and functions on class like addClass, toggleClass etc. does not store the actual class to add the prefix.

Any idea ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: use a for loop and store every class in a variable then add the prefix to the variable then change the class value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to store every class in a var and concat it with the prefix then remove the old class and set the new one .

```
$( "code" ).each(function( index , elm ) {
  var oldClass = $(elm).attr('class');
  newClass = 'language' + classVal ;
  $(elm).removeClass(oldClass);
  $(elm).addClass(newClass);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve all the `code` elements, check what class they have, and rename it by deleting then adding the new one.

```
$("code").each(function(index, elt) {
  var jqElt = $(elt);
  var eltClass = jqElt.attr('class');
  jqElt.removeClass(eltClass);
  jqElt.addClass('language-'+eltClass);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var classes = ['bash', 'markdown'];
for (let i = 0; i < classes.length; i++){
  $(`.${classes[i]}`).removeClass(classes[i]).addClass(`language-${classes[i]}`)
};
```

`$('.class')` finds the elements with the class, `.removeClass('class')` removes the initial class, and `.addClass('language-class')`

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below which will work well when you have `multiple classes` as well if suppose,

```
$('code').each(function() {
  var elm = $(this);
  var classes = elm.attr('class');
  classes.split(' ').forEach(function(class){
    elm.removeClass(class);
    elm.addClass('language-' + class);
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ClassList to get list of all classes.

Here it is just one class,just prepend it with "language-" and update the classlist again

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var codeElements = $('code');
  var length = codeElements.length;


  codeElements.each(function(item) {
    var classList = codeElements[item].classList;
    var newList = [];
    classList = "language-" + classList;
    codeElements[item].classList = classList;
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<code class="bash">

<code class="markdown">
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

A straight forward replace on the class attribute should work fine

```
$('.bash, .markdown').attr('class', function(_,klass) {
    return klass.replace(/(bash|markdown)/, "language-$1");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here another demo with different class scenarios: (prefixes the succeeding classes if element has 2 or more class)

```js
$('code').each(function(index, item) {
    if ($(item).attr('class') === undefined) return; // if no class at all do nothing
    
    var classList = $(item).attr('class').trim().replace(/(\s+)/g, ' ').split(' ');
    var className = classList.map(function(val, ndx) {
     return val = `language-` + val;
    }).join(' ');
    $(item).attr('class', className);
})
```

```css
code {
    display: block;
}

[class^="language-"] {
    color: crimson;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Different scenarios of classes</h4>
<code class="bash">initial Class: "bash"</code>
<code class="markdown">initial Class: "markdown"</code>
<code class="bash random">initial Class: "bash random"</code>
<code>initial Class: No class</code>
<code class="bash what  ">initial Class: "markdown what&nbsp;&nbsp;"</code>
<code class="      extra things">initial Class: "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;extra things"</code>
<code class="random     items">initial Class: "random&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;items"</code>
```